# NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to work using pygame here. I have imported pygame. Then, when I do pygame.init(), it fails. Not sure, what the issue is, and couldn't get a proper response anywhere. Thanks for your help.

Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "python", line 1, in <module>  
NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? Maybe you installed pygame with pip instead of pip3 or the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install pygame using `pip install pygame`? If yes and you are still getting the error then it's quite likely that you named your project file `pygame.py` that will shadow the actual pygame module causing issues like this. So renaming your file should fix the problem. Never name your python files same as the module files.

Comment: file name is different. It is not same as pygame. And yes, using pip, i had installed.

Comment: Are there any other files in the directory with name pygame.py ? Cause the error is `NameError` and not a `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: No. there is no other file or any directory with this name.